# Which version of Django rest framework for Django 2.1.5?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am working with an old django version, and I can't identify which version of django rest framework  I would need for a Django 2.1.5

I can't find this information in the official [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#requirements) documentation

Thanks

Comment: mention the django version you are using.

Comment: @Abhijithk already mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the version of 3.11.1, which it the latest drf version for Django 2.1.

- https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.11.1/docs/index.md#requirements
- https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/tree/3.11.1/docs
- https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/tree/3.11.1

```
Python (3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8)
Django (1.11, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 3.0)
```

> The documentation are replaced from the website. But you can use above links to check the documentation by using markdown based.

You can also easily check to the tags itself: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/tags, to check the old versions.

Answer (score 0):

**Requirements for rest framework**

REST framework requires the following:

Python (3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10)

Django (2.2, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 4.0, 4.1)

source: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#requirements